# no viable conversion from returned value of type 'void'

Tags: c++, function, promise, g++, future

i user future to block this thread and get value,here is my code

```
typedef struct a{
   int num;
}a_t;
a_t methodA(future<a_t> fA){
    a_t ret = fA.get();
    return ret;
}
```

and in another thread ,i use promise to set value,here is my code

```
promise<a_t> aPromise;
a_t aT={};
aT.num=10;
aPromise.set_value(aT);
```

but it got error with "no viable conversion from returned value of type 'void' to function return type 'a_t' "

why it causes that?

thany you for your help!

Comment: What line of code produced that error message?

Comment: “return ret” this line，@David Schwartz

Comment: That first block of code compiles just fine for me with no errors or warnings if I add `#include <future>` and change `future` to `std::future`.

Comment: i already add "#include <future>" and "using namespace std;" in my code.@David Schwartz

Comment: Then if you're getting an error on that `return` line, it's because there's some issue before it in code not shown. [That code compiles just fine.](https://onlinegdb.com/BkVIIe8CL)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in C++ you don't need that `typedef struct ...` dance. `struct a_t { int num; }; a_t object;` works just fine.